# Including Azure Function trigger parameters in AppInsights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

We have two Azure Functions instances (Node on AzFn v1, and .NET Core on AzFn v2). Both are configured for AppInsights, but all of the invocations don't provide any specific details for the trigger.

Ideally I'd like to see URL (for an HTTP Trigger), Blob path (Blob Trigger), etc. Is this something that can be configured or is it simply a limitation of Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the trigger info you seek is not logged as `traces` if we don't log them by ourselves. So My suggestion is to log the trigger metadata directly in our code, check [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---metadata) of the trigger we need.

For example,

- .Net Core Functions

  - Http Trigger url `log.LogInformation(req.Host.Value + req.Path.Value)`
  - Blob Trigger path Add `string blobTrigger` in method signature and `log.LogInformation(blobTrigger)`
- JS Functions

  - Http Trigger url `context.log(req.originalUrl)`
  - Blob Trigger path `context.log(context.bindingData.blobTrigger)`

Incidentally, see some data already available in Application Insights.

For Http trigger, in v1 functions, we could track `requests` items to see `url`. While in v2 the [request detail logging](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2447) is still in process hence info like url is unavailable.

For Blob trigger, in v2 functions, we could track `dependencies` items to see the blob url in `data`. No similar content in v1.